# MongoDB 2.0.42 : Pushing to a nested array?

Tags: arrays, json, node.js, mongodb

Hi guys I've been stuck on this problem for a while now. 
So I have a JSON object that looks like this in my MongoDB database:

```
{
  "gameID" : 900000001
  "characters" : [
    {
      "characterID" : 1
      "inventory" : [
        "item1"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

How do I use this bit of JSON to add into the inventory array?

```
{
  "gameID" : 900000001
  "characterID" : 1
  "inventory" : [
    "item2"
    "item3"
  ]
}
```

I've tried using multiple different findOneAndUpdate operations and updateOne operations but I can't seem to access the inventory array in character. I always seem to push "item2" and "item3" into incorrect spots. I've done a lot of research about this and found some interesting reads.

[push into deeply nested array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27709993/push-into-deeply-nested-array)
This answers to this question hint that it might be impossible with MongoDB 2.0.42. If I'm unable to do this then can someone point me to the next best method?

Also, why can't I use the latest version of MongoDB in npm? Npm seems to only allow up to version 2.0.42 to be installed. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, you are on the latest version (2.0.42) of the [mongodb driver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb) , not mongodb itself. If you want to check the version of the database itself, type this into command line:

```
mongod --version
```

I would use the [positional operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) and the $each operator, which allows you to append multiple values to a list.

```
db.collection.updateOne({
    gameID: 900000001,
    "characters.characterID": 1
},
{
    $push: {
        "characters.$.inventory": {
             $each:["item2", "item3"]
        }
    }
})
```